# How can I ensure that the messages sent are not lost when the kafka is not working?

Tags: apache-kafka

I've started to use Kafka. And I have a question about it.

If Kafka is not running because of network problem, kafka crash etc. how can I eliminate this problem? And, What happens to messages that was sent to kafka?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all brokers in the cluster are unavailable your producer will not get any acknowledgements (note that the actual send happens in a background thread, not the thread that calls `send` - that is an async call).

If you have `acks=0` then you have lost the message but `acks=1` or `acks=all` then it depends on retry configuration. By default the producer thread retries pretty much indefinitely which means at some point the send buffer will fill up and then the async send method will fail synchronously, but if your client fails in the meantime then the messages in the buffer are lost as that is just in memory.

If you are wondering about behaviour when some but not all brokers are down, I wrote about it [here](https://chrisg23.blogspot.com/2020/02/kafka-acks-configuration-apology.html)

Comment: By the way, one way to ensure nothing is lost is not to publish directly, instead store your pending messages persistently and have a background job sending them, deleting in the acknowledgement callback.